# is there any healthy patients?

Tags: meaning-in-context

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3735754/

Taking care of sick patients

Why the above title is not "Taking care of patients"? I think all of patients are sick. is there any healthy patients? I guess "sick patients" are a special group of patients. If so, what kind of patients are sick patients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People often go to doctors when they are healthy, in order to ensure that they stay healthy. The doctor can take your vital signs, possibly take your blood, etc., to check for anything that might make you sick eventually, but that does not mean you are sick now.

Comment: You may want to say more explicitly what “patient” means in English. Is someone getting a flu shot from a clinic a “patient” or a “customer” or something else?